# Trying to get a large centered background image to work in mobile browser without being distorted

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

So i used the method in this article: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

here's the code i have:

css:

```
#bg {
height: auto;
left: 0;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1024px) {
#bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
}
```

html:

```
<img id="bg" src="breakfast.jpg">
```

this works for the most part except the height/width ratio in the mobile browser is messed up.

Comment: Why not use CSS `background-size`??? That's the standard way of achieving this kind of thing.

Comment: doesnt work in the mobile browser how i want it to. doesn't fill the page as desired

Comment: There are many variants for background-size: cover, contain and custom px or % values. You can center with background-position, it's hard to believe none of them fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Edit you're media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {

#bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    min-height: 1px;
    height: auto;
}

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, makes the image default width to 100% and maintains the aspect ratio for height not filling the page in portrait mode.

Comment: Here is this what you want I made a jsfiddle you can input your own dimensions for the image as well. http://jsfiddle.net/VG4w4/1/

Comment: Nope, same issue, the width of the bg is 100% and the height does not fill the page in portrait mode.

Comment: Ohh, so you want to the image to fill the height 100% in portrait mode, but not lose any aspect ratio? If that is the case, you have to load a different image.

Comment: Roger that, will do. Thanks.

Comment: Actually i fixed this by just using this css and adding height: 100% to the html css element.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question. In order for the background image to fill the page in mobile browser while maintaining the correct aspect ratio one must add a media query with a re-sized image for portrait / landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the fix:

Needed to add

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```